# Pandas: iterate over a row and adding the value to an empty column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Hello there I would like to iterate over the row CPB% and add the computations to a related column called 'Proba'. My dataframe looks like this: [image]

What I tried so far looks like this:

```
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, num=100)
dCPB = df['CPB%']
df['binnedB'] = pd.cut(dCPB, bins)
dfnew = pd.DataFrame(pd.cut(df['CPB%'], bins=bins).value_counts()).sort_index(ascending = True)
dfnew['binned'] = dfnew.index

total = dfnew['CPB%'].sum()
idx = total

for index,row in dfnew.iterrows():
  idx = idx - row['CPB%']
  row['Proba'] = float(idx) / float(total)
```

But my iteration does not update my empty column Proba, any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: Please paste your dataframe as text and not an image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is, you are assigning the result back to the `row`, which doesn't get stored anywhere. instead you can do:

```
proba = []

for index, row in dfnew.iterrows():
    idx = idx - row['CPB%']
    proba.append(float(idx) / float(total))

dfnew['Proba'] = proba
```

However, this is not the best way, you can use `.apply` with `axis=1` to do row-wise calculations on a data frame.

Comment: Yes thanks but I have another issue error: 'Cannot concatenate object of type "<type 'float'>"; only pd.Series

Comment: You would need to use `proba = []` instead of `proba = pd.Series()` here. But not really necessary when you can use `cumsum`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`pd.Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) to perform your iterative deductions:

```
total = dfnew['CPB%'].sum()
dfnew['Proba'] = 1 - df['CPB%'].cumsum() / total
```

With Pandas you *should* look to vectorise algorithms, which usually involves column-wise operations as opposed to a row-wise `for` loop. Here's a complete demonstration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list(range(1, 7))})

def jpp(df):
    total = df['A'].sum()
    df['Proba'] = 1 - df['A'].cumsum() / total
    return df

def yolo(df):
    total = df['A'].sum()
    idx = total

    proba = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        idx = idx - row['A']
        proba.append(float(idx) / float(total))

    df['Proba'] = proba
    return df

# check results are the same
assert df.pipe(jpp).equals(df.pipe(yolo))

%timeit df.pipe(jpp)   # 691 µs
%timeit df.pipe(yolo)  # 840 µs
```